# Multiple and unique questions with plagiarized answers: Solution to keep questions answered and give credit?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

The main problem I see with the solution of removing plagiarism in this case is two-fold. There may exist questions that are different and distinct that two different people seeking will arrive at and they may share the same solution in part or wholly. If one question was found to have a plagiarized answer and it is removed then you are doing a dis-service to another person that will later arrive at the question which was answered, the knowledge is in SO but not is properly linked. The second problem with the solution is that now the credit is not stolen but is also not giving any extra credit to the original answer poster.

Comment: That's why we have duplicate questions. Instead of RE-answering with the same answer, link as a dupe

Answer (score 10):

There are three possible situations here:

1. The plagiarized answer doesn't actually answer the question.

   In this case deleting it isn't any loss.
2. The plagiarized answer answers the question.

   Then the answer should be deleted and the question closed as a duplicate of the question that had the content that was plagiarized.
3. The answer that was plagiarized was posted to the same question.

   In this case the answer is still there on the question after removing the plagiarizing answer, so there's no problem.